# How to describe ‘when’ a black hole actually is?

Tags: black-holes, spacetime, time, event-horizon, causality

If I look at any point in space I can think of it as being in the future because it takes me time to travel there. I can go there and an observer can watch me go there.

When I look at a black hole I can also think of it as being in the future because it takes me time to travel there. I can go there but an observer cannot see me go there.

By going to the black hole, my future and the observer’s future become different. I remain at a fixed point in their future, unable to go further but I actually go further, towards my own future.

These futures become separated.

So, if I’m telling a friend about black holes and point to one, I can’t realistically point at anything but the event horizon.

How do I describe the interior?

How can I even think about something that isn’t there until I go there?

Is it something like: “Inside that invisible object I’m pointing at is a future that’s beyond our future?”

Or should the situation best be described mathematically?

This would all be much easier if we just said that $T = 0$ really does mean ‘The End’ but it doesn’t  seem like we can be sure of that.

Comment: Couldn't one equally regard a point in space to be in the past, because the light you see from it generates an image from its previous state in time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I describe the interior? How can I even think about something that isn’t there until I go there?

It seems to me that the future is always that way, whether it's a black hole interior or not.

It's true that when there is a black hole, people can end up stuck in distinct "branches" of the universe in the sense that they can never meet or communicate again. That also happens in the dark-energy-dominated future phase of cosmology, though there's no singularity there.

But even if one of them is inside a black hole and one is outside, it's essentially a symmetric situation: Alice can never again meet Bob, and Bob can never again meet Alice.

I would just say that the black hole interior is in the future, though in some sense it is a different future than the one outside.

Comment: If I’m an observer outside a black hole, then there are spacetime regions of the black hole’s interior that are not in my casual future. This events do not have definite causal ordering with respect to me, and really can’t be described as being “ in my future “ at all.